# I bought a disk without an AppId, what do I do?

Tags: steam, pc, civilization-5

I've recently bought a disk copy of *Civilization V*, and whenever I try to install the game, it pops a message "No AppId configured", what can I do?

Notes:

- This WAS a legal purchase, not a burned disk or copied program
- I have installed Steam and created an account
- I came here out of desperation, as Steam's support didn't have an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the upper left corner in steam under "Steam" there should be an option called "Backup and Restore games"

Click this and choose "Restore a previous backup"

Change the directory by pressing "Browse" to your CD-ROM (usually located on D:)